# Какие существуют способы расположения элементов на форме?

Tags: layout, java, swing

Писал раньше в NetBeans, делал формочки в GUI редакторе. Решил поднять скилл. Пересел на IDEA, и начал делать формы вручную кодом. Какие есть способы расположение элементов на форме, кроме расположения по координатам и расположения с помощью Layouts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Единственным способом расположения виджетов являются Layout. Расположение виджетов по координатам фактически это частный случай Layout (иногда называется AbsoluteLayout).

Сложные вариации расположения элементов делаются через вложения Layout'ов или через кастомные лэйауты.

Визуальные примеры стандартных лэйаутов можно [посмотреть здесь](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cit591-2004/Pages/layout-examples.html)

Answer (score 1):

почитайте [это](http://skipy.ru/technics/layouts.html)